# How to create Account from Contact detail page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I know we can create detail object from the master object by default. Like we can create contacts from account. But now I got a requirement to create Account from a Contact detail page. As we know, only the visualforce page which is using Contact standardcontroller can be added into a Contact page layout. But to call create() on Account, we have to use Account standardcontroller. So I tried to create a custom button calling a visualforce page which is using Account standardcontroller. Like below:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts" tabStyle="account">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!create}" value="Create New Account"/>
            <apex:repeat value="{!accounts}" var="a">
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="3" >
                    <apex:outputText value="{!a.Name}"/>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!a.BillingCity}"/>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!a.Phone}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:repeat>   
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

But I got the error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: You cannot call create() on a non-null object .

I do not know how can I solve this problem now. Could anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to be using the Account New action, rather than calling create:

```
action="{!$Action.Account.New}"
```

Comment: I think you need to throw the URLFOR on that...`{!URLFOR($Action.Account.New)}`

Comment: I didn't actually try the code but thought that might have been for when you use the link tag as opposed to a button... will have to check and find out!

Comment: Thank you both. Now the button works perfectly now. I voted up for both of you.

Answer (score 1):

Very quick 'n dirty idea: how about "quick create"? Doesn't fit all cases but worth knowing about :^]

1. Setup > Customize > User Interface > **Show Quick Create**

   [image: setup quick add]
2. Create new detail record and open the lookup to the master

   [image: account lookup]
3. hit the **new** button

   [image: search]
4. create the master record

   [image: new account record]

Caveats:

- won't display all fields!
- won't work on all objects!
- won't always be able to apply your validation rules!

Comment: This is also an interesting answer which I did not know before. I voted up.

Comment: thanks :^] appreciated, considering you were already down the Visualforce path